# CSS Module Overriding UI Styling

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

so I'm using Material UI Components on my react-app, for example for a button text, I would like to give it a margin-top and font-weight, however, I'm using CSS Modules, so I cannot just override the default CSS Styles, so I had to use the !important flag, is there a cleaner/better approach to do this and avoid using the better flag? Here's an example of what I'm looking like for a certain component.

[image]

I was adviced to use atomic CSS but googling that it seems like they're advising me to use in-line styles and that's something I've been meaning to avoid for future reusability.

TIA

Comment: I'm not aware of Material UI so I don't know if there is a better answer out there, but could you order your stylesheets so that your external stylesheet is last, making it override any other styles. This should hopefully avoid the `!important`

Comment: How can I do so?

Comment: How is the Material UI css referenced?

Comment: an import in my react app's app.js

Comment: In the JS?! How so? If that is the case, I dont think my answer will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got through by setting specific CSS classes, for example for this font weight and margin top, my new CSS looks like

```
.loginSignUpLink.priority {
    margin-top: 4%;
    font-weight: 1000;
}
```

and my classname is as follows

`className={classNames(styles.loginSignUpLink, styles.priority)}`

Answer (score 0):

Using important in CSS is not a good way. I prefer you please use the parent class or tag to avoid important.
**One main thing is very important your CSS run last after all CSS files. It is the most important.**
For example please check the below code.

```
<div class="test">
   <span class="span"></span>
</div>
```

Than write down css for span like this

```
div.test span.span{ ... }
```

Also, you use more hierarchy to avoid important in css

```
body div.test span.span{ ... }
```